# Как правильно использовать метод Contains()

Tags: c#, linq

Здравствуйте!

Скажите, как правильно использовать LINQ , а именно метод Contains() в таком контексте:

У меня есть список строк. Каждый из такого списка я должен обрабатывать в цикле, кроме списка в котором есть такая последовательность символов  **"MIP**.

Для этого я использую такой код:

```
 foreach (Match match in matchesPolicy)
        {
             while (match.ToString().Contains("\"MIP")==false)

             lst_policy2.Add(match.ToString());

        }
```

Явных ошибок VS не выдает. Но и результата тоже нет( вывода нужных строк в TEXTBOX).

Примечание.
без строчки кода

```
while (match.ToString().Contains("\"MIP")==false)
```

Все выводится в текстбокс ,как надо.( Но и строки с **"MIP**. Вот как такие строки исключить?

изменил внутри цикла:

```
string substring = match.Value.ToString().Where(s => !s.Contains("\"MIP"));

lst_policy2.Add(substring);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас либо пустой, либо бесконечный внутренний цикл (поскольку `match` не изменяется внутри цикла) — это раз.

Затем, не пользуйтесь `ToString`: его результат не документирован. Если вам надо значение отматченной строки, [документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) подсказывает, что надо пользоваться свойством `Value`.

Ну и если вам нужен просто список строк, не содержащих данную подстроку, почему бы не сделать проще:

```
originalList.Where(s => !s.Contains(substring))
```

?

---

Если вам нужно добавить в список, попробуйте так:

```
lst_policy2.AddRange(originalList.Where(s => !s.Contains("\"MIP")));
```

Циклы и вообще регулярные выражения при этом не нужны. (Или может быть, я не понял задачу?)

---

Если регулярки нужны, должно подойти такое

```
foreach (Match match in matchesPolicy)
{
    if (!match.Value.Contains("\"MIP"))
        lst_policy2.Add(match.Value);
}
```

Это же можно записать в виде

```
lst_policy2.AddRange(
    matchesPolicy.Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(match => match.Value)
                 .Where(v => !v.Contains("\"MIP")));
```

Comment: @VladD,спасибо за ответ!(как всегда). Следуя вашим замечаниям, я исправил код и добавил в вопрос! но только все равно-ошибка. ( Ошибка 2 char не содержит определение для "Contains", а перегрузка лучшего метода расширения "System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)" содержит несколько недопустимых элементов

Comment: @vlazarev: обновил ответ, посмотрите теперь.

Comment: Изначально регулярки мне нужны. Они "отматчивают" нужные куски строк(блоки из нескольких строк). Затем в цикле foreach я должен взять каждый блок строк ( match.ToString()), чтобы вывести его в textbox. Но мне совершенно не нужен то блок строк(match), который содержит "MIP.

Comment: Проблема, что я не могу ( казалось бы очевидно) приспособить оборот Where(s => !s.Contains("\"MIP")))  к моему match...

Comment: @vlazarev: Тогда возможно вам нужно

    foreach (Match match in matchesPolicy)
    {
        if (match.Value.Contains("\"MIP"))
            lst_policy2.Add(match.Value);
    }

?

Использование `ToString` — не самая лучшая идея.

Comment: О Вот! Спасибо! Вопрос решен!

Comment: @vlazarev: отлично, перенесу в ответ